# Sine calculation with Taylor series not working

Tags: java, function, math, trigonometry

I wrote a sine function in Java, that should calculate the sine of x like

[image: wikipedia image]

My function looks like

```
public static double sine(int x) {
    double result = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n <= 8; n++) {
        double temp = 2 * n + 1;
        result += Math.pow(-1, n) * Math.pow(x, temp) / fact(temp); // fact() calculates faculty
        
    }
    return result;
    
}
```

Only a few decimal places match to Math.sin(), but only if x is smaller then 6 and the limit of n equals to 8.
Sometimes, if x is greater than 6 sine() returns even 4.106 or if limit of n is greater than 32, it returns NaN or -Infinity...
What am I doing wrong?

Hope you can help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: **B-b-b-b-b-b-b-BUFFER OVERFLOW!!!1!** (Okay, technically an integer overflow, but that doesn't sound as fun to wrestl-ize)

Comment: Try using `BigInteger`s.

Comment: so double is not enough? But is that the reason why the result sometimes is 4.106?

Comment: Factorials grow fast. Really fast. Faster than the "Well, that escalated quickly!" meme from The Anchorman. You'll need to use `BigInteger`s and `BigDecimal`s (or be careful in how you construct your terms) in order to avoid overflowing.

Comment: @JackManey: The real issue seems to be that x is too big for the Taylor formula to have good convergence.

Comment: Why is your `sine` method taking an `int`?

Comment: Keep in mind, Taylor series expansion works on radians, not degrees, so if your passing degrees rather than radians, you're not going to get the results you're expecting.  Try converting to radians first.

Comment: It may be profitable to evaluate this polynomial in Horner form instead of relying on `Math.pow` and your `fact`.

Answer (score 3):

With such a low value of n, the Taylor series is a poor approximation of sine for high numbers.  For degree 8, any angle higher than around 4 will produce a significantly inaccurate result.

Because sine is periodic, one easy solution would be to modulus divide the angle (in radians) by 2*pi.  The `StrictMath` Class in Java reduces the angle in a different way but the idea is the same.  In that case, they reduce the angle to between `[-pi/4, pi/4]` to improve accuracy.  [This tool](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hmmutc9ija) demonstrates how accuracy improves as the degree of the Taylor series increases.

Comment: So I have to convert the angle to radians with StrictMath.toRadians(x)?

Comment: No, I was just explaining how the sine function in Math works.  You should write your own function to convert angles to that range, though.

Comment: In retrospect, the angle should be reduced to [-pi/2, pi/2].  I misunderstood what the method in StrictMath was doing.

Comment: One other thing, modulo with negative numbers is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a step back, the astonishing fact is that the sine series evaluates to a bounded function in the first place. After all, it is a power series closely related to the exponential function. That the polynomials that occur as partial sums have large values for large arguments is a general property of polynomials and thus not astonishing at all.

---

Avoiding the recomputation of recursive functions like powers of the same argument and factorials is always a good idea. Thus a reduction to (a minimal amount of) elementary arithmetic operations looks like this:

```
public static double sine(int terms, double x) {
    double result = 1;
    double mxx = -x*x;
    double addens = 1;
    double temp = 2;
    for(int n = 2; n <= terms; n++) {
        addens *= mxx/temp++/temp++;
        result += addens; 
    }
    return x*result;

}
```

Note that the type of x is now double.

---

Another breaking condition for the loop would be

```
   while(1+addens != 1)
```

to use a flexible number of terms until the contribution of addens becomes negligible. This gives accurate results for a larger range of arguments, however for large arguments the cost will dramatically increase.

Then one can explore a halving-and-squaring strategy with a simultaneous computation of sin and cos.

Answer (score 1):

As monolyth421 already mentioned, your problem is that the Taylor expansion works good for **small** (close to zero) values of x. 
If you want to obtain a good accuracy, you should consider reducing the argument to the interval [-pi/2 , pi/2] (using [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Symmetry.2C_shifts.2C_and_periodicity)) and then use the Taylor expansion. Only a few terms should be then enough to get good accuracy.